# Корень вопросительного местоимения

Tags: местоимение

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой корень в слове "кто": кт или кто?

Answer (score 3):

> какой корень в слове "кто": кт или кто?

Гм…

Вот что пишет о слове кто **Шанский** в книге *"В мире слов"* (М., 1978):

> Это слово появилось на свет как сложное. Его сложили из двух
>   местоимений: относительно-вопросительного местоимения ***къ*** и
>   указательного ***то***.
>
> Заметим, что в ***кто*** старые ***къ*** и ***то*** полностью
>   растворились и сейчас никак уже не ощущаются…

И далее **Шанский** пишет о том, что  в настоящее время по соотношению с падежными формами *к-ого, к-ому, к-ем, о к-ом* в именительном падеже в слове ***кто***  можно выделить окончание ***-то***. Т. е. тогда корнем и в  именительном падеже (как и в косвенных падежах) в слове ***кто*** будет ***к.***

Но не у всех словаристов в слове ***кто*** выделяется окончание ***-то.***

Так,  **Тихонов** *("Словарь-справочник по русскому языку", М., 1997)* в именительном падеже слова ***кто*** не выделяет окончания, т. е. всё слово ***кто*** у него является корнем (в косвенных падежах происходит усечение корня до ***к***).

В вышедшем в этом году *"Большом универсальном словаре русского языка"* **под ред. Морковкина**  — другой взгляд на морфемное членение слова ***кто.***  Авторы словаря выделяют в именительном падеже в  слове ***кто*** окончание ***-о***, корнем же считают ***кт***: ***кт-о.***

Так что... выбирайте, ***Олеся***, какой из этих вариантов Вам больше нравится!

Comment: Ух ты, у меня тезка есть?! Впрочем, он не прав. А в каких словах еще есть такой корень?

Answer (score 1):

Корень -к-.

КТО. Общеслав. Сложение местоим. къ (см. кой) и усилительной частицы *то.* Того же корня, с чередованием ъ/ь, что и *что.*
Яндекс.Словари › Этимологический словарь. — 2004

Answer (score 1):

Вообще говоря, в местоимениях выделять корень - не самая благодарная задача. Можно говорить о родственности слов, и тут словари помогают (см. Екатерина Каштанова), но искать корень в чистом виде не стоит: такие дебри исторические, а ценность результата сомнительна. Лучше уж воспринимать как данность, неким самодостаточным иероглифом. Так что в чисто практических целях "кто" лучше считать отдельным корнем. Но никак не "кт", это противоречит и исторической правде, и практической надобности.